# optimize Azure DB Synchronisation with iOS Application

Tags: ios, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I am using Azure app service with pricing tier S1 and Azure SQL DB of pricing tier S1 for an iOS application
I have done below settings for optimize Azure DB Synchronisation.

1. Made data centers of azure app service and azure database are same (Southeast Asia).
   2.Increased app service instances to 2.
   3.change app url to http instead of https.
   4.create INDEX ON in perfomence insight.
   5.changed page size to 1000 from 50.
   6.created new framework with NSHttpUrlSession re-use in the iOS SDK
   But still database synchronisation takes 14 seconds in 3G (for 1700 records and 7 tables).

Can performance be still optimised?

Comment: Not sure what your question is. You've given no information about the database details on the iOS side of things. And we have no idea how large your database records are. But you're syncing over 100 records per second according to your details. Also, just an aside: the entire world is moving from http to https, not the other direction.

Comment: In iOS Application i am using CoreData with SQLite. I am pulling 1700 records (7 tables).

Comment: Agreed - we need more information on your database.  Also, are you using incremental sync?    14 seconds on 3G with that number of records doesn't seem unreasonable.  What are your expectations?

Comment: Yes, we are using incremental sync. When application loads initially we need to call pullWithQuery (for 1700 records and 7 tables) and we are depending on 3G. In-house application we are using mobilink (Sybase) for database synchronization. It takes only 2 sec.